# how to rotate a vector in 3d space around arbitrary axis

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d, transformation, rotations, quaternions

In my case I have two arbitrary vectors (suppose vector AB and CD ) and I am assuming that some rotation operation will happen to vector AB to get it the orientation of vector CD. so by using the knowledge the positions (cartesian coordinates) of both the vectors (already known) can I find the angle of rotation between them around some arbitrary axis of rotation in space?
Can I reproduce vector CD by using the knowledge of their positions and angle between them?

Basically I am not dealing with vectors but 3 dimensional objects with multiple cartesian coordinates in my system. so using the information of cartesian coordinates of both objects I want to do operations at first object to transform it to the second object. I hope the you are convinced with what I am trying to explain.

Comment: Rotating one vector onto another in three dimensions is not unique. To see this consider the obvious rotation around a mutually orthogonal axis. Then consider rotating around the axis which lays in the plane with AB and CD, bisecting the angle between them. This second rotation will always be 180 degrees and swaps them two vectors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can you please elaborate the procedure that you have mentioned above.

Comment: Say we take $(1,0,0)$ as the vector we wish to rotate to the position$(0,1,0)$ and we first choose the axis of rotation to be $(0,0,1)$. This will rotate the x-y plane counterclockwise by $\pi/2$ radians. Instead we could have chosen the axis of rotation to be $(1,1,0)$ and rotate by $\pi$ radians around that axis.

Comment: The fact that you call your vectors AB and CD suggests that you are not working with simple three-dimensional vectors. How many coordinates do you use to specify a single vector? Three or six?

Comment: @David K in fact the system I am dealing with is not simple 3D vectors but sort of objects containing multiple coordinates. so its like rotating one object in such a way that it will get the orientation of other object . the information I will have is the position of both orientation in form of cartesian coordinates using that I want to reproduce any of the object. I hope that you are convinced what I am trying to say.

Comment: Supposing the objects are airplanes (just an example of a shape), we could rotate one aircraft so its nose points in the same direction as the other; we could make the nose point in the same direction **and** roll the aircraft so the the "top" of each aircraft is facing the same way; or we could do those things **and** move the aircraft to the same place as the other aircraft. In the first two cases the positions of the aircraft don't matter.

Comment: two aircrafts situated randomly in the space. what maths I need to do the transform or align the aircrafts. I don't know the exact maths behind it but I am assuming some rotation must have happened to orient one aircraft like the other? I want the mathematics behind it. I will be happy knowing that.

Answer (score 1):

The angle between two unit vectors $u$ and $v$ is given as

$$
\theta = \arccos\left(u^\top v\right)
$$

the shortest axis of rotation is the vector orthogonal to both vectors, and can be found using the cross product

$$
s = \frac{u \times v}{\lVert u \times v\rVert}
$$

In most cases, $s$ should be normalized, even if $u$ and $v$ are already both unit vectors.

(note that switching the order of the cross product will give you the negative of the axis.  The right-hand rule determines the order)

To create the rotation matrix that rotates $u$ into $v$, we can use the axis-angle formula for rotation matrices:  (taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle))

$$
R = \begin{bmatrix} 
\cos\theta + s_x^2 (1-\cos\theta) & s_x s_y (1-\cos\theta) -s_z \sin\theta & s_x s_z(1-\cos\theta + s_y \sin \theta \\
s_y s_x (1-\cos\theta)+s_z \sin\theta & \cos\theta + s_y^2 (1-\cos\theta) & s_y s_z (1-\cos\theta) - s_x\sin\theta \\
s_z s_x (1-\cos\theta) - s_y \sin\theta & s_zs_y(1-\cos\theta) + s_x \sin\theta & \cos\theta + s_z^2(1-\cos\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and now you can compute

$$
v = Ru
$$

and

$$
u = R^\top v
$$

Comment: hey thank you so much for your efforts. can I use the same method to transform the three dimension object containing multiple coordinates?

Comment: Without knowing more about you particular application, I can't say for sure, but I think it would.